# Classes in Django views.py - confused

Tags: python, django, biopython, pubmed

I couldn't find the answer to my question here, which probably means I'm barking up the wrong tree.

I have a Django site where I would like to create a page that uses BioPython to retreive the last x records from PubMed for a specific search string. The BioPython output is tricky, so to get the title and abstract I played around and wrote some test code that outputs a dictionary that could be looped over in a Django template. (thanks to Marco Bonzanini https://gist.github.com/bonzanini/5a4c39e4c02502a8451d)

```
from Bio import Entrez
from pmterm import term

def search(query):
    Entrez.email = 'david.hallsworth@x.com'
    handle = Entrez.esearch(db='pubmed',
                            sort='pubdate',
                            retmax='20',
                            retmode='xml',
                            term=query)
    results = Entrez.read(handle)
    return results

def fetch_details(id_list):
    ids = ','.join(id_list)
    Entrez.email = 'david.hallsworth@hotmail.com'
    handle = Entrez.efetch(db='pubmed',
                           retmode='xml',
                           id=ids)
    results = Entrez.read(handle)
    return results

title_abstract = {}
if __name__ == '__main__':
    results = search(term)
    id_list = results['IdList']
    papers = fetch_details(id_list)
    for i, paper in enumerate(papers['PubmedArticle']):
        title = (paper['MedlineCitation']['Article']['ArticleTitle'])
        abstract = ''
        try:
            for a in paper['MedlineCitation']['Article']['Abstract']['AbstractText']:
                abstract += (a + " ")
        except KeyError:
            abstract = 'No abstract available'
        title_abstract[title] = abstract
```

However, I now realise that I also want to store the citation and link url, so a dictionary probably isn't the way forward. In my current site I have saved articles in a model and display them like this:

```
<div>
    <h2>{{ entry.title }}</h2>
    <h4>{{ entry.authors }} ({{ entry.year }}) {{ entry.journal }}</h4>
    <h4>Reviewed by {{ entry.author.first_name }} {{ entry.author.last_name }} on {{ entry.date_added|date:'M d, Y'}}</h4>{% block header %}

<div>
    <h2>{{ entry.title }}</h2>
    <h4>{{ entry.authors }} ({{ entry.year }}) {{ entry.journal }}</h4>
    <h4>Reviewed by {{ entry.author.first_name }} {{ entry.author.last_name }} on {{ entry.date_added|date:'M d, Y'}}</h4>
    <a href="{{ entry.pub_med_url }}" target="_blank" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-book"></span> view on PubMed</a>

    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <h4> Abstract </h4>
            <h5>{{ entry.abstract }} </h5>
            <h4>Full citation</h4>
            <h5>{{ entry.citation }}</h5>
        </div>
    </div> <!-- panel -->
</div>

{% endblock header %}

    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <h4> Abstract </h4>
            <h5>{{ entry.abstract }} </h5>
            <h4>Full citation</h4>
            <h5>{{ entry.citation }}</h5>
        </div>
    </div> <!-- panel -->
</div>
```

The thing is, the new references will be throw away and I don't necessarily want to save them to the database. The only way I know to make an object with many sub-elements is using a class, but I'm not sure a class-based view is what I want.

Can anyone point me in the right direction? Thanks very much!

Comment: I'm not sure why a dictionary wouldn't work. You can nest dictionaries arbitrarily.

Comment: Thank you. I wasn’t aware that you could iterate through nested dictionaries with template tags in Django, but that makes sense. Thanks.